# Apply excel formulas with xlsxwriter (or another engine)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I create with pandas and xlsxwiter an excel file with some formulas and, from that file, I have to create another one. Thus I need the formulas to be applied and the right values being set on load.
On windows the best solution I've found is the following:

```
def __applyExcelFormulasOrPromptToDoItManually(self, filename):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        # NOTE: In order to get the real values of the columns, we have to apply formulas.
        # The easiest way is to open the xlsx with excel, save it and close it
        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
        workbook.Save()
        workbook.Close()
        excel.Quit()
    else:
        input('Please open the generated file with Excel, save it, close it and press enter...')
```

Now I'm moving this to a cron job on AWS that runs on linux and cannot have human interaction.
How can I apply formulas?
I don't know if I can install libreoffice on that image.

Comment: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html As per the docs, you can add the "value" parameter to worksheet.write_formula(), and work out the value of your formula using python code. Unfortunately this may not be a very nice way of doing it, but I haven't been able to find a work around

Comment: Thanks @mrblue6 but I solved in another way. The formula was just a lookup so I wrote in python code what the formula is doing and all is solved